# Newlines in javascript within a PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php

I've written some PHP which encases some javascript within a PHP variable, like so:

```
$js .= 'response['.$x.'] = FinanceDetails("'.$finance_code.'",' . $cart_value . ','.$minimum_deposit.','.$total_cost.');';
```

But this can be repeated up to three times, and then it's injected between `<script>` tags and I'd like it to show like so:

```
response[0] = FinanceDetails("ONIF12",290.00,10,1500);
response[1] = FinanceDetails("ONIF6",290.00,10,1500);
...
```

But currently it shows in one long string as there are no line breaks. I've tried adding `\n` and `\r` as well as `\n\r` together at the end of the `$js` value but I just keep getting an Illegal character error - how would I implement a new line / line break in this situation?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: @RayonDabre nl2br won't work, since he is writing out javascript code. The code would just contain `<br>` then, which is invalid javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `""` quotation marks instead of `''` to be able to print out newlines. For example:

```
$js .= 'response['.$x.'] = FinanceDetails("'.$finance_code.'",' . $cart_value . ','.$minimum_deposit.','.$total_cost.');' . "\n";
```

Otherwise PHP does not parse the newline and your code ends up with a "\n" in it.

Comment: Perfect answer - had a funny feeling I'd seen something similar before with the single / double quote, thank you